# BIRT : Data set with dynamic table name

Tags: birt

I'm new to Birt, so I might be doing this the wrong way...

What I need to do is to display some statistical data in reports.
Data will be prepared overnight in some special tables (I wanted to use materialized views, but haven't been able to find it in Birt report designer when connecting through JDBC to my DB - so I'll be using tables instead).

The typical chart I need to draw is :
- month on X-Axis
- a value on Y Axis.

For the Y Axis, there will be multiple series... But I don't know how many. Each serie data will be fetched from one of those special report table I was talking just above.

I have two main problems :
- how to display N series on a chart, N being unknown ?
- how to dynamize table names in a data set ?

Is there a more Birt-ish way to do so ? Maybe I have it completely wrong from the beginning, really don't know.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For using MViews, consider creating a SYNONYM for the MView. Then configure BIRT to show synonyms in the JDBC dataset preferences (displayed as a checkbox "Show Aliases" in the JDBC dataset editor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databases don't allow to dynamize table names with a regular query parameter, so we need to handle this by script.

The cleanest way would be to do this with a DB stored procedure: the BIRT dataset query just invokes a stored procedure of your DB with the table name as parameter. Here is an example of a such dataset query with MySql JDBC:

```
CALL `myschemaname`.`mystoredprocedure`(?);
```

Here, the question mark '?' is a query parameter, in the dataset editor we link it to a report parameter representing the table name. Then this stored procedure builds a dynamic query and returns relevant data.

Another option is to inject the table name in "beforeOpen" script of the BIRT dataset:

1- In your dataset, initialize the query with an arbitrary valid table name, for example:

```
select *
from myvalidtablename
```

2- In Eclipse designer select your dataset -> Script tab -> beforeOpen

Assuming the table name is in a report parameter:

```
this.queryText=this.queryText.replace("myvalidtablename",params["myTableNameParam"].value);
```

Concerning how to handle N series, it depends on how datarows are designed in tables. Two main cases:

**Case 1** - Series are in multiple rows such:

```
month1;serie1;value
month1;serie2;value
month2;serie1;value
month2;serie2;value
```

This is the smartest case because it is dynamically handled in a BIRT chart with "Option Y series grouping". This is how [this chart](http://www.visioneo.org/economic-detail-simple-layout) works: country field is set as optional grouping and BIRT handles everything.

**Case 2** - Series are in multiple columns:

```
month1;valueSerie1;valueSerie2
month2;valueSerie1;valueSerie2
```

In this case we need to declare each serie explicitely. In the chart editor, by dropping down "Value (Y) series" menu we can create as many series as we like.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the data representation tip. I used the "series in multiple rows" approach. BTW, the reports you mentionned are really cool - is visoneo your product ? How do you style so fine the reports is it all just CSS ?

Comment: Yes it is :) These reports are designed using 100% the native styling features of BIRT Eclipse designer, however i admit it requires a little bit of practice to get this kind of result. I am glad if this might give valuable ideas for your own reports.